# How to avoid NullPointerException in Java executable jar?

Tags: java, swing, jar, nullpointerexception

I minimize the application to reproduce the error. I used Java 8 and IntelliJ Swing Designer to make this minimum GUI app.

```
public class MyGui {
private JList<String> docList;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private DefaultListModel<String> listDocModel;

public MyGui(){

    listDocModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

    try (InputStream resource = MyGui.class.getResourceAsStream("/data.csv");
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            listDocModel.addElement(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    docList.setModel(listDocModel); // I didn't initialize docList. But it works when run from the IDE.  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyGui");
    frame.setContentPane(new MyGui().mainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 800, 800));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Later I made a jar using maven-assembly-plugin. When I run the app as `java -jar myap.jar`

I got this null pointer exception :-

Exception in thread

```
"main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.example.MyGui.<init>(MyGui.java:30)
        at org.example.MyGui.main(MyGui.java:38)
```

Line 30 is `docList.setModel(listDocModel);` So my question how come that work by IDE but doesn't work form jar. By the IDE my list is filled with data as:-

[image]

To fix this I tried following update:-

```
   docList = new JList<>(listDocModel);
   mainPanel = new JPanel();
   mainPanel.add(docList);
```

After this my list is empty no more data:-

[image]

So how do I make my list with data and make an executable `jar`?

Update full project:-

https://github.com/masiboo/SwingGui

Comment: Is `data.csv` correctly included in the .jar file? Edit: come to think of it: there's way too much that shouldn't work. Can you provide the full real code?

Comment: Pls check the here https://github.com/masiboo/SwingGui

Comment: 1) Don't post code in githup. The [mre] should be posted in the forum. 2) the suggestion was that the jar file was not created correctly. I've never used an IDE to generate a jar file. Read the Java tutorial on [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html). You need to make sure the "data.csv" file is included as part of the jar file.

Comment: I posted compete project but still @JoachimSauer wanted to see full real code. I used maven-assembly-plugin to generate jar. Also, it is not about the reading resource data.csv. It is null pointer for docList. That works fine by IDE but null pointer form the jar.

Comment: @camickr *"You need to make sure the "data.csv" file is included as part of the jar file."* Indeed yes. That `String` would suggest it needs to be in the root of the Jar, which would be unusual. It's more typical to place resources in a sub-directory like `resources` - which most build systems will automatically copy into the archive. So .. did you run the Jar tool to list the Jar content? Another way to examine it (on Windows at least) is to change the file type to `.zip` and explore it using the built-in Windows file management. *"I posted .. project.."* An MRE is better, stick with that.

Comment: I check and set trace to see is it loading data.csv. it is loaded and I can read. There is not problem with it. The problem is docList nul.

Answer (score 1):

```
// I didn't initialize docList. But it works when run from the IDE.
```

In that case, it is the IDE that is the problem. Possibly doing a 'clean and build' will shake the gremlins out, but I can't provide support for IDEs.

**The `docList` (`mainPanel` etc.) *all* need to be instantiated before use.**

In addition to that, the list needs to be put on a container that is visible on the GUI, preferably wrapped in a scroll pane (as this example does).

[image]

Final note: It got to the point in comments, that the 'file loading was fine'. That's a good time to factor it out of the example and use hard coded data as below. The MRE below does that - so anyone can run it to see it work (or fail). Prepare and post a minimal reproducible example like this for the best help fastest.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyGui {

    // what happens in the IDE is irrelevant, this needs to be instantiated
    private JList<String> docList = new JList<>();
    // .. as does this
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private DefaultListModel<String> listDocModel;
    // if the problem is not I/O related, factor it out by hard coding data
    private String[] data = {
        "Apples,are,Crunchy",
        "Oranges,are,Orange",
        "Bananas,are,Bent",};

    public MyGui() {
        listDocModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

        for (String line : data) {
            listDocModel.addElement(line);
        }
        // I didn't initialize docList. But it works when run from the IDE.
        // THEN THE IDE IS THE PROBLEM. Possibly fixed with a 'clean and build'.
        docList.setModel(listDocModel); 
        
        // now add the list to the panel! 
        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(docList));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyGui");
        frame.setContentPane(new MyGui().mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Avoid guesses, pack will produce the min size needed to display GUI
        //frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(..));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```